# Using Voice Assistants (Siri or Google) to control launch and actions in an app - React Native

Tags: react-native, voice-recognition, google-assistant-sdk, siri

I have an app developed using react native running on both IOS & Android platforms. I am currently exploring the option of controlling the app - Launching & actions within the app using the native voice assistant like Siri / Google Assistant .
Is there a library available to do the same or will I have to create bridges ?

I have looked at 3rd party voice assistants, but am looking for the IOS/Google native assistants as these are more well maintained and standardized for future use.